# Set Field Text, Java

Tags: user-interface, jtextpane

I have two classes. MetaDataExtractor(GUI) and MetaData.

MetaData has the method which extracts the metadata from an image. MetaDataExtractor is designed to display the data in a JTextPane. (Please excuse the class names. I know it's a little confusing. I'm fairly new to Java).

MetaDataExtractor:

```
LongitudeField.setText("" + MetaDataTags.getLongitude());
```

MetaData:

```
public String getLongitude() {
    try {
        Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);
        if (metadata.containsDirectory(GpsDirectory.class)) {
            GpsDirectory gpsDir = (GpsDirectory) metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
            GpsDescriptor gpsDesc = new GpsDescriptor(gpsDir);
            String Longitude = "" + gpsDesc.getGpsLongitudeDescription();

        }
    } catch (ImageProcessingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error 1");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error 2");
    }        
    return longitude;
}
```

If I set the longitude to be displayed in the JTextPane, it returns "null". If however, I set it to print out on the command line, it prints the longitude fine?

Please excuse me if its a simple solution. I'm still getting to grips with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is case sensitive and declare firstly your variable outside of try & catch statement.

Use a IDE like Eclipse to reduce syntax errors like these.

so you should have :

```
public String getLongitude() {
    String longitudeDesc ="";
    try {
        Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);
        if (metadata.containsDirectory(GpsDirectory.class)) {
            GpsDirectory gpsDir = (GpsDirectory) metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
            GpsDescriptor gpsDesc = new GpsDescriptor(gpsDir);
            longitudeDesc = "" + gpsDesc.getGpsLongitudeDescription();

        }
    } catch (ImageProcessingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error 1");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MetaData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Error 2");
    }        
    return longitudeDesc ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tchike, that makes no difference. If I was to add the line,"System.out.println(gpsDesc.getGpsLongitudeDescription());" into MetaData it prints the longitude. As soon as I add it to a string, it appears to be "null".

Comment: Although probably not the correct way of doing it, I've managed to fix it by adding this line into MetaData. "                String longitudes = gpsDesc.getGpsLongitudeDescription();
                
                longitude = longitudes;"

Comment: Did you try to replace "longitude"  by "Longitude"? Because Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes. But it said that "It hides a field".

Comment: Just had a look at your edited answer. I assume it said "It hides a field" as I declared it as a String.

Comment: I think this is because there is already a variable defined "longitude" that is available to this method.